# how to i specify the upper and the lower value of a color in HSV opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

I found way to convert RGB to HSV, but still I am unable to find the upper and lower value of color. How to do i calculate that?

I have to take out the pickachu from the image

[image]

and this my code till now

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


    lower_red = np.array([30,50,50])
    upper_red = np.array([255,255,180])  #it is trial and error

    mask = cv2.inRange(frame, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
       break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

please help me

Comment: so, what color do you want to extract?  Yellow? That is around Hue = 60, so in openCV (at least C++, not sure about python) it is around hue = 30. Try lower = np.array([20,50,50])
upper = np.array([40,255,255])

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393191/micka thank you but still some above portion on the right side is till not visible

Comment: try allowing smaller saturation and value (2nd and 3rd param in lower range) and/or allow more hue variation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following program to find the upper and lower hue values for the pixel by clicking on it(i.e. the pixel you want).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image_hsv = None   # global ;(
pixel = (20,60,80) # some stupid default

# mouse callback function
def pick_color(event,x,y,flags,param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        pixel = image_hsv[y,x]

        #you might want to adjust the ranges(+-10, etc):
        upper =  np.array([pixel[0] + 10, pixel[1] + 10, pixel[2] + 40])
        lower =  np.array([pixel[0] - 10, pixel[1] - 10, pixel[2] - 40])
        print(pixel, lower, upper)

        image_mask = cv2.inRange(image_hsv,lower,upper)
        cv2.imshow("mask",image_mask)

def main():
    import sys
    global image_hsv, pixel # so we can use it in mouse callback

    image_src = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])  # pick.py my.png
    if image_src is None:
        print ("the image read is None............")
        return
    cv2.imshow("bgr",image_src)

    ## NEW ##
    cv2.namedWindow('hsv')
    cv2.setMouseCallback('hsv', pick_color)

    # now click into the hsv img , and look at values:
    image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image_src,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    cv2.imshow("hsv",image_hsv)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```